# Python: How to pass non-ASCII file names to Popen on Windows?

Tags: windows, file, process, python-2.7

When I run a subprocess with Python, everything id fine with ASCII params but it fails if a parameter is an unicode (cyrillic) string:

```
cmd = [ 'dir.exe', u'по-русски' ]
p = subprocess.Popen([ 'dir.exe', u'по-русски' ])
```

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process.py", line 48, in <module>
    cyrillic()
  File "process.py", line 45, in cyrillic
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python\27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python\27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 870, in _execute_child
    args = '{} /c "{}"'.format (comspec, args)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 8-10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried different executables - 7z.ex, ls.exe - popen fails before even running them.

But what if I encode unicode string to a specific encoding?

```
# it works because 1251 is kinda native encoding for my Windows
cmd = [ 'dir.exe', CYRILLIC_FILE_NAME.encode('windows-1251') ]

# fails because 1257 cannot be converted to 1251 without errors
cmd = [ 'dir.exe', BALTIC_FILE_NAME.encode('windows-1251') ]

# this may work but it's not a solution because...
cmd = [ 'dir.exe', BALTIC_FILE_NAME.encode('windows-1257') ]
```

The "bad" thing, I have different file names on my computer - baltic, cyrillic and many more. So it looks there is no general way to pass a non-ASCII file name to Popen on Windows?! Or could that be fixed still? (Without dirty hacks preferably.)

Windows 7, Python 2.7.3

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, but it looks as if `cmd` mixes an ASCII string with a Unicode string.  Perhaps this is causing trouble when Popen merges the strings together to form the command line?  I suggest you try making both strings Unicode.

Comment: `cmd` is not unique in that - the problem happens running `mplayer` also. Making both args unicode didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, there doesn't appear to be any option to make Popen use Unicode, so (if nobody has a better answer!) you might have to work around the problem.  It would be reasonably straightforward to write a C program that took a UTF-8 command line, converted it to UTF-16, then executed it.

Comment: Oh yes, Popen does not work with unicode. Moreover it works only with ASCII. (I will update my initial post with new details).

Answer (score 1):

If you use Python 3, it will pass the parameters properly as Unicode. Assuming your subprocess can load unicode parameters on the command line (Python 2 cannot), then it should work.

For example, this script, when run under Python 3, will display the Cyrillic characters.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["powershell", "-c", "echo", "'по-русски'"])
```